# where to look for docs of write function of C

Tags: c, manpage

I did `man open` it shows the proper function with the arguments and details.
But when I do `man write` it shows the write command and not the definition
for the C function which is used like `write(fd, a, length)`
Where do I access the Docs for this C function?

Comment: Try `man 2 write`.

Comment: I always get happy when people post questions that shows that they want to learn how to solve things themselves.

Comment: Have a look here: https://linux.die.net/man/2/write or here https://linux.die.net/man/3/write

Comment: The numbers (2,3) are sections, see `man man` for their explanation.

Comment: man 2 write does it!! Can we do similar thing with `tldr` also ?

Comment: I sometimes use `man -a <stuff>` and iterate over all pages if I don't know which one I want. You can also do `man 'write(2)'`. `Can we do similar thing with tldr also ?` What is "tldr"? There's `apropos write`

Comment: https://tldr.sh/  This I recently came to know is something called more readable or friendly man pages.  Do you guys suggest any better alternative to man pages when you want to write C code stuff ?
`man -a` simple but really cool command

Comment: Why should we use something else than "man", it is just fine? Anyway, you might like to try `apropos write`...

Comment: `man 2 write` will give you the section 2 (system calls) manual page of write.